# How to update Order data in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order

I have to update some sales order parameters

```
$order = $this->orderInterface->loadByIncrementId('000000009');
 $order->setStatus($status)
       ->setState($status)
       ->save();
```

Here `save()` is `@deprecated` and also if try to save, it does not save.

I tried:

```
/**
*  @var OrderStatusApiInterface
*/
$this->orderRepositoryInterface->save($order);
```

It changes all the other data also is completely false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `OrderRepositoryInterface` to load the order and `ResourceModel` to save order. I tested follow code and it's works fine at my local Magento.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResourceModel
) {
    $this->orderResourceModel = $orderResourceModel;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function execute()
{
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get(1);
    $order->setCustomerEmail('new@amasty.com');
    $this->orderResourceModel->save($order);
}
```

Comment: saved my time +1

Answer (score 0):

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{    
  protected $resultJsonFactory;  
  protected $_orderRepository ;

   public function __construct(
     \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderRepository,
     \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
   ) {
   parent::__construct($context);
   $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
   $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
} 

  public function execute()
  {
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
    $orderId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('OrderId');
    $_order = $this->_orderRepository->load($orderId); // it order is not order increment id
    if($_order->getId()){
        $_order->setCustomerEmail($email);
        $_order->save();
         echo "Saved";
    }else{
        echo "Error:Not Saved";
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Update customer order data through code in magento2.x