# Magento 2 Custom flow - Order status not updating after invoice creation

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Normally, Magento will set the Order status to `Complete` once invoice is created but I want to set it to `processing` for some reason.

I have tried using these events:

- sales_order_invoice_pay
- sales_order_invoice_register
- sales_order_invoice_save_after

but still no luck.
When I log the Order status after saving, it logs the correct updated status but the order still proceeds to complete (both UI and database).

Here's what I did so far:

```
/**
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}


/**
 * @param Observer $observer
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();

    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($invoice->getOrderId());
    $this->logger->info('i am here!'); // this works
    $this->logger->info($invoice->getOrderId()); // this works

    $this->logger->info($order->getState()); // state new
    $this->logger->info($order->getStatus()); // status pending
    
    $order->setStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
            ->setState(Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
        $this->orderRepository->save($order);

    $this->logger->info($order->getState()); // state updated processing
    $this->logger->info($order->getStatus()); // status updated processing
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that does not use raw query.

**Interface: Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface**

I found this link [How to update Order data in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150053/how-to-update-order-data-in-magento-2)
but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sales_order_invoice_register that is right after the invoice has been created and before the first save in the database.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_invoice_register">
        <observer name="event" instance="Module\Name\Observer\InvoiceRegister" />
    </event>
</config>
```

This event is also triggered if invoices are created automatically.